# Creating a table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create two tables in SQLite, but the app keep crashing.
Below is my code

```
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    String queryUser_Details = "CREATE TABLE user_details ( user_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, " +
            "gender TEXT, hairColor TEXT, weight TEXT, height TEXT, age TEXT, comment TEXT)";

    database.execSQL(queryUser_Details);

    String queryUser_Activity =
            "CREATE TABLE user_activity ( detail_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, location TEXT, note TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(user_Id) REFERENCES user_details(user_Id))";

    database.execSQL(queryUser_Activity);

}
```

Comment: And what is the crash you're seeing? Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

**REFERENCE** is misspelled: it needs a final S: **REFERENCES**.
For reference (oh! what a funny joke!): https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html